# SVN client on windows without administrator rights

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to install an svn client on a friend's work windows laptop without much success. It seems that everyone is using TortoiseSVN nowadays, which unfortunately doesn't install without administrator access. Is there any way around it or another client I can try?

I don't need anything fancy - just basic http/https, but a GUI is very much preferred over a command line client.

Thanks!

---

I just verified that both SmartSVN and RapidSVN mentioned previously require administrator access to insatll on Windows, just like TortoiseSVN.

:(

Comment: The SmartSVN Portable edition (available on their website) works fine.

Comment: @mindmatters I can find no such download on their website?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/693498/1725096

Answer (score 22):

Ok, I finally found out the (I think) correct answer to this question. The zipped binaries are available in the win32svn project here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/.

In the subdirectory of your favorite version, just download the file that has a name like svn-win32-1.6.16.zip and unpack to your home dir, local hd or (in my case) usb stick.

Hope this helps someone! I was very surprised to find all links I found pointed to installers which you may not be able to run when you don't have adminstrator rights.

EDIT: this is, of course, the CLI version; I guess this answer is more for people who, like me, are looking for it and arrived at this question :)

Comment: all I needed! This works on Win7 without admin rights. Thank you!

Comment: Those are not clients. Those are servers.

Comment: Perhaps, but this is the only package without an installer I could find that includes the client files.

Answer (score 2):

http://portableapps.com/node/6767

RapidSVN Portable

Comment: The downloads are no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

This is a late answer, hope it help someone else. My answer is [smartsvn](https://www.smartsvn.com/), it is a perfect software, with foundation version free to use.

In their download all page, you can download a [portable version](https://www.smartsvn.com/downloads/smartsvn/smartsvn-windows-portable-9_2_3.zip), jre is also included in this zip package, that means you can even run the software without java installed, since java is not included by default in the latest windows system.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [huge list of them here on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients), that should give you a few options, but I believe that [SmartSVN is good](https://www.smartsvn.com/) (not used it, only had a look)

Comment: I used it. Its ok. The portable edition comes with 31 days of free use. This is direct link for download portable edition http://www.wandisco.com/get?f=smartsvn/smartsvn-portable-8_0_1.zip

Answer (score 1):

RapidSVN works quite happily without being installed.

Unfortunately - it's only packaged as an installer exe.

What you need to do is install RapidSVN on some machine where you DO have admin rights, and copy the RapidSVN folder from program files onto a USB drive or the hard drive of the machine you want to run it on. You can then run 'RapidSVN.exe' from any machine, and it works quite happily.

Comment: In the latest version downloaded from here - http://portableapps.com/node/6767 - it seems you only need to copy the  \App\RapidSVN folder after you've run the self extracting zip

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest if some gui is needed is to use Eclipse with svn plugin only.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to use RapidSVN, I've used it before without admin access

then I know you still need admin rights for this one below, but let me mention this as someone might find it useful, if they want to toggle the contextmenu on/off

How to Enable or Disable TortoiseSVN Menus Easily
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21106/how-to-enable-or-disable-tortoisesvn-menus-easily/