# What Subversion clients for Windows are there that do not need installation?

Tags: windows, svn

A colleague of mine agreed to using Subversion (SVN) for our little project, but only if he doesn't have to install it. He has a [U3 USB stick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U3) where he keeps the project files and he would like the SVN client to live there as well. I tried searching for a non-installable SVN client, but couldn't find anything (although I suspect that many of the available clients would run if just copy-pasted from an installation folder). What can be recommended?

I'd really like to get version control going. It would be best if it had a GUI for merging files too, not just the command line.

**Added:** The copy-paste from an existing installation is one solution, but I'd like to see first if there perhaps isn't some client that does not require installation by design. If not, I guess RapidSVN is nice enough (although it does leave stuff in Windows registry).

Comment: @Vilx: Extract the files from the binary installer and you'll save yourself a lot of time (see updated answer).

Comment: The copy-paste from an existing installation is one solution, but I'd like to see first if there perhaps isn't some client that does not require installation by design.

Comment: Hm, okay. In that case, there's a packaging of RapidSVN as a PortableApp (of http://portableapps.com fame).

Comment: what counts as "installation"?

Comment: That you have to run a .exe file which installs its files somewhere in the system. I want something that you just extract from a .ZIP file, copy to some location of your choosing (like an USB drive), and it works.

Comment: Too many programs suffer from the "I'm so important I must be specifically installed on your computah"-syndrome.

Comment: Mostly I don't mind an installer and even prefer one, but I think that if an application works in the simple copy-paste mode, then a .zip file should also be provided.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try **[RapidSVN](http://www.rapidsvn.org/index.php/Main_Page)**. The [**CollabNet binaries**](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/) can be used in a similar fashion for command-line support. Yes, these have installers, but you can simply copy the binaries around -- I use **[Universal Extractor](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Compression-tools/Universal-Extractor.shtml)** to get the binaries out without having to run the installer.

Also, an enterprising user has packaged **[RapidSVN as a PortableApp](http://portableapps.com/node/6767)**. There is an "installer", but it really just unzips things into a directory of your choice and writes a default configuration file into that directory.

Comment: The copy-paste from an existing installation is one solution, but I'd like to see first if there perhaps isn't some client that does not require installation by design.

Comment: @Vilx if you are not going to copy the file(s) to your system how do you expect to execute them? or more directly _all_ the clients where you can simply copy an existing installation has no requirements fulfills the "no installation".

Comment: @RuneFS - What I mean, that there are clients that require running a `setup.exe`, and there are clients that only require opening a ZIP file and running the `.exe` within. In the former case, I don't know if it will work nice and stable, because maybe the setup did something else to my system too (like installing MSVCRT). So it will run fine on my machine, and the machine on my work (because I have the appropriate versions of VS itself installed), but when I go on vacation and try to use it from my laptop, it suddenly doesn't work.

Comment: @RuneFS - In the ZIP file case, there is a guarantee, that the ZIP file already contains all of the necessary pre-requisites.

Answer (score 7):

Try [Alagazam.net's Subversion Windows Installer](http://alagazam.net/). There is also a version with just the binaries without an installer.

Comment: This is perfect. Alagazam provides a build that you can download as a plain zip, ready to go.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with the copy and paste the bin folder from [SlikSVN](https://sliksvn.com/download/).

It seems like SlikSVN is the underlying platform behind several graphical SVN clients. In my experience it seems stable and reliable.

Specifically, the bottom link on [this page](http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=91&expandFolder=91&folderID=260) seems to be a non-install/xcopy precompiled package (although I haven't tried this one myself, only inspected it). It does not appear to be the newest, though. You might do your friend a favour by installing [the newest SlikSVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download) on your own computer, and then share the bin files with your codeveloper.

Comment: The copy-paste from an existing installation is one solution, but I'd like to see first if there perhaps isn't some client that does not require installation by design.

Comment: The SlikSVN binaries work fine if you just copy them, but you can find also find a zip file with binaries on the tigris.org link from http://subversion.tigris.org/getting.html (Look at the 2.2 link for 1.6.0 releases)

Answer (score 2):

If Java is available on the machines you could use [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/).

Answer (score 1):

There's a portable version of [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/) which is what I use. It's a pretty good SVN client, but it needs [JRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine#Execution_environment). It has a nice GUI and all.

Answer (score 0):

There is a portable version of [RapidSVN](http://www.rapidsvn.org/index.php/Main_Page) [here](http://portableapps.com/node/6767). Just install it to a flash drive.

Comment: Where can you see the single-exe version? I only see a single .exe that is an installer. And that installs a whole bunch of files.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative two should be pretty sufficient.  But both methods requires installing it to the USB device which I guess is similar to just copying onto it.  I [checked Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients) and there are some standalone listed there.

---

[SmartSVN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SmartSVN), [QSvn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QSvn) (portable version requires install), and [Syncro SVN Client](https://svnclient.oxygenxml.com/) (they have versions which requires you to extract and run), etc.  But does it copy, and does it run any different than installing to the USB?

---

**Alternative One**
Load Cygwin on the USB device, install SVN support and run it off of that.  There isn’t any up (which I assume is more than possible) since I've had the luxury of using TortoiseSVN (requires install).

**Alternative Two**

Install TortoiseSVN on a USB device and use if off of that. It has a GUI interface for merging and diff.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218904/how-do-i-automate-keeping-my-tortoisesvn-project-up-to-date) may be relevant to your interest.  However, Google has some results indicting they are slow.

Comment: Both answers seem weird to me. First - why use Cygwin when SVN can be easily compiled for Windows too? Second - AFAIK Tortoise is a shell extension, and that does not run well from a USB drive...

Comment: Yes, those two choices aren't the greatest under your particular environment.  However, the Wikipedia article has links to many standalone application (none of which I can speak for).  One such is SmartSVN which has a portable version.

Comment: Additionally, if leaving stuff in the registry is that big of a problem why not use a program like Sandboxie to install which leaves no traces (unless you count the registry entries made by Sandboxie).  Putting "extra" entries into the registry isn't going to make a big difference performance wise.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the command line client that I had installed onto a USB stick. I then whipped up a couple batch files that did the basic checkout, checkin stuff, and one batch file that gave me a command prompt with a [PATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) set.

It doesn't have all the integration of something like [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN), but I don't think you would be able to easily do that from a USB stick.

Comment: The thought also occurred to me, however things get a bit messy when you get to merge files...

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem, and thought it would be easier to find than it is. Bert Huijben posted the solution as a reply to Cecil, but his link was outdated.

http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=8100

Scroll to the bottom where you can grab a ZIP file of the binaries. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, there is an [PortableApps version](http://portableapps.com/node/13470) of [RapidSVN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RapidSVN):

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative which may be acceptable to some users:

The [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) IDE is portable (not entirely; it depends on Java). Use the Eclipse SVN plugin ([Subversive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients#Descriptions) or [Subclipse](https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse)). This takes care of the daily needs.

You may choose to point to a Java Portable installation to make it truly portable. However, I believe it might be slow to run off a USB pen drive.

Comment: Yeah, I remember Eclipse as being a bit big and bulky. Though I haven't worked it for several years.