# SVN client without context menu integration?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, contextmenu

I'm using TortoiseSVN with Windows 7 right now. It integrates into the context menu. I'm looking for a similar SVN client that does not integrate into the context menu. Preferably a standalone (no install) version of TortoiseSVN.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What subversion clients for Windows are there that do not need installation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693498/what-subversion-clients-for-windows-are-there-that-do-not-need-installation)

Answer (score 0):

Just get the command line version:

http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure all the context integration is in the registry somewhere.  You could install it and then remove the context part.  Never tried copying binaries from one machine to another but that might do the trick as well.