# Why can't I set TChromium cookie storage path in chrome browser default path?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, chromium, tchromium

I have read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269587/how-do-i-clear-the-cache-and-cookies-for-an-embedded-chromium-browser) about how to set cookie storage path, and I want to

set my cookie in the same path with chrome browser default cookie path.

This is my code.

```
var
  CookieManager: ICefCookieManager;
  dir: string;
  setSuccess: Boolean;
begin
  dir := GetSpecialFolderPath(CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA, True);
  dir := dir + '\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default';//Chrome browser cookie path.
  CookieManager := TCefCookieManagerRef.GetGlobalManager;
  setSuccess := CookieManager.SetStoragePath(dir);
  if setSuccess then
    ShowMessage('set new path success!!');
end;
```

The message show, it means that Seting Storage Path is success.

When I executed my program and loaded my gmail with TChromium browser, it still
remain in login console, even without login information.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you execute your costom browser and chrome browser at the same time.

Looks like cookies is locked when chrome browser is executing.

Comment: thanks for reply. As your guess, I executed both of them, but I can copy the file called 'cookies' in chrome. It's that means the cookie file is unlocked?